# How do I copy a mixed or fully upper case table name from one postgres database to another?

Tags: postgresql

I am having some difficulty getting a table with an entirely uppercase name to copy from one postgres database to another.

Based on posts here and elsewhere, I have been using the following syntax at command line:

```
pg_dump -t tablename fromdb | psql todb
```

The database names are all in caps as well, though that hasn't proven to be an issue.

Here is the line I need to run more or less:

```
pg_dump -t "COMMS" "DB_V1" | psql "DB_V2"
```

When transferring a table with a name that is all lowercase in double quotes (as a test case) it works perfectly and has no problem with the database names being all caps and double quotes.  When trying to transfer a table name that is in all caps however, it cannot find it.  "pg_dump:  No matching tables were found"

Based on reading elsewhere, I've tried using '"COMMS"', as well as different permutations just to see if they would work.  Based on that reading, I really expected the double quotes inside single quotes to work.

Is there an established practice for this that I am missing in my research?  I realize there is likely a very simple answer out there.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't you just need to get the quotes past the shell and into PostgreSQL? `pg_dump -t '"COMMS"' '"DB_V1"' | psql '"DB_V2"'` for example.

Comment: As I mentioned in the post, I've tried that.  Interestingly, the name of the database holding the table and the name of the database to copy to can be including in caps with just double quotes and as long as the table name is lowercase it works just fine.  Putting the single quotes outside the double quotes doesn't seem to change anything...

Comment: Right, sorry, missed the `'"COMMS'"` stuff.

Comment: Also of note, this method for copying tables (from a db with postgis enabled to another with postgis enabled) does not seem to copy over the geometry values for the copied table.

Comment: `pg_dump` version? `'"tablename"'` should work...

Comment: Hi, I was working along this blog post, and it covers also a mix of specific schema / specific table name / mixed case settings: http://sptl.eu/2015/01/03/backup-a-mixed-case-table-from-a-specific-schema-via-pg_dump/

Answer (score 5):

Adding backslash before double quotes works at windows cmd shell

```
pg_dump -t \"TableName\" MYDB
```

Comment: This also works on linux based systems as well. Tested on centos 7.